# Добавление на панель текстового редактора Quill кнопок, позволяющих вставить в текст Material Icons

Tags: javascript, google-fonts

В админке одного сайта используется в качестве текстового редактора QUILL Rich Text Editor.
Я хочу дать пользователю возможность добавлять в текст небольшой набор предопределенных иконок (Material Icons, потому что они вписываются в стиль сайта). В коде html это выглядит как `<i class="material-icons">[name of icon]</i>`
Как я вижу это.

- 1 шаг - добавить в место, где сейчас установлен курсор, текст с
  названием иконки [name of icon]
- 2 шаг - установить выделение на только что набранный текст
- 3 шаг - обернуть его в тэг `<i class="material-icons"></i>`
- 4 шаг - снять выделение, пользователь продолжает писать текст.

Что я сделала (на примере иконки с названием grade):

```
let Inline = Quill.import('blots/inline');

class gradeBlock extends Inline{    
    static create(value){
        let node = super.create();
        node.setAttribute('class','material-icons');
        return node;    
    }    
}

gradeBlock.blotName = 'gradeblock';
gradeBlock.tagName = 'i';
Quill.register(gradeBlock);

var quill = new Quill('#editor-container', {
  modules: {
    toolbar: [
      [{ header: [1, 2, false] }],
      ['bold', 'italic', 'underline'],
      ['image', 'code-block', 'gradeblock']
    ]
  },
  placeholder: 'Compose an epic...',
  theme: 'snow'  // or 'bubble'
});

var customButton = document.querySelector('.ql-gradeblock');
    customButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
    console.log('Clicked!');
        let mergeFieldText = "grade";
        var selection = quill.getSelection(true);  //find position of cursor
        quill.clipboard.dangerouslyPasteHTML(selection.index, mergeFieldText); //paste "grade" into the ql-editor content
        quill.setSelection(selection.index,5); //set selection on text "grade"
        var range = quill.getSelection();  
        quill.formatText(range,'gradeblock'); //add tags <i class="material-icons"></i> around the selected text 
        quill.setSelection(null); //reset the selection
});
```

Но это не работает так, как мне нужно.
После первого нажатия на мою кнопку добавляется чистый текст "grade". После повторного нажатия - после (!) текста "grade" появляется нужная мне иконка Material Icons, но при этом если начать набирать дальше текст, то физически он остается внутри тега `<i></i>`.

Пожалуйста, помогите найти ошибку. Я не понимаю, что делаю не так.
Почему не срабатывает первое нажатие? Как мне сделать так, чтобы дальнейший текст оставался внутри текущего `<p></p>`, но снаружи от `<i></i>` Может быть, есть какой-то совсем другой легкий способ решить мою задачу?

Попробовать мой или свой код можно тут: https://quilljs.com/playground/#quill-playground

Comment: Ок, частично я проблему решила, поняв, что половину шагов можно заменить одной функцией insertText():

`customButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
let mergeFieldText = "grade";
var selection = quill.getSelection(true);
quill.insertText(selection.index, mergeFieldText,'gradeblock');
});`

Теперь при первом клике на кнопку добавляется в текст нужная иконка, но дальше текст все равно остается внутри тегов `<i>` и сбрасывается это только при повторном клике. Причем дальше добавляется неформатированный текст "grade". По сути, кнопка работает в режиме вкл/выкл. Как это исправить-то?